# Prove $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ { x }_{ n }^{ k } } ={ \left( \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ { x }_{ n } } \right) }^{ k }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that the limit of the sequence $x_n^k$ is the same as the limit of $x_n$ all raised to the $k$th power.  Prove $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { x }_{ n }^{ k } } ={ \left( \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { x }_{ n } }  \right)  }^{ k }$$

Comment: We need some conditions: If $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $k=2$, one limit exists and the other does not.

Comment: Sorry you are to assume that {Xn} is a convergent sequence, and that k is a natural number.

Comment: Supposing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists and is equal to $L$, we want to show that $x_n^k$ gets arbitrarily close to $L^k$. Given that $(x_n^k - L^k) = (x_n - L)(x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + L^{k-1})$, can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so just to clarify would I take M to be equal to epsilon divided by the infinite polynomial such that for all n>M we have our desired result?

Comment: @JustinStevenson what infinite polynomial? The $(x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + L^{k-1})$ has always a finite number of terms (for a given $k$): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers

Comment: Ah yes I guess it is finite, anyhow would I still set M equal to epsilon divided by the finite polynomial.

Comment: @JustinStevenson not quite. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=M$. Then, $(x_n)$ is bounded and thus there is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|x_n|\leq c,\quad\forall\ n\in\mathbb N.$$

Furthermore, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb  N$ such that
$$n>n_0\quad\Rightarrow\quad |x_n-L|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2|M|},\quad|y_n-M|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2c} .$$

As a consequence,
$$n>n_0\quad\Rightarrow\quad |x_ny_n-LM|\leq |x_n||y_n-M|+|M||x_n-L|<c\frac{\varepsilon}{2c}+|M|\frac{\varepsilon}{2|M|}=\varepsilon.$$

This proves that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n\cdot y_n)=LM=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n\right)$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n\cdot x_n\cdots x_n)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)\cdots \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)^k$$

Answer (score -1):

For $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $M_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies:

$$|x_n - L| < \epsilon, \forall n > M_1$$

So $x_n$ converges to $L$. We need a similar result for $x_n^k$ and $L^k$. So, for any $\epsilon' > 0$, we want to show existence of a $M_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies:

$$|x_n^k - L^k| < \epsilon', \forall n > M_2$$

But:

$$|x_n^k - L^k| = |(x_n - L)(x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1})|$$

$$= |x_n - L| |x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|$$

Take $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon'}{|x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|}$. By hypothesis, there existis $M_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies:

$$|x_n - L| < \epsilon, \forall n > M_1$$

Therefore:

$$|x_n^k - L^k| = |x_n - L| |x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|\\ < \frac{\epsilon'}{|x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|} \cdot |x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|$$

$$|x_n^k - L^k| < \epsilon'$$

for all $n > M_1$. Taking $M_2 = M_1$ gives the result.

Comment: Thank-you, that makes sense.

Comment: In the definition of limit, $M_1$ depends on $\epsilon$ and have to be independent of $n$. In your solution, $M_1$  depends on $n$ (because $M_1$ depends on $\epsilon$ which, according to your choice, depends on $n$). You have to use the boundedness of the sequence to estimate $|x_n^{k-1} + x_n^{k-2}L + \cdots + x_nL^{k-2} + L^{k-1}|$ by a constant $C$ and then choose $\epsilon=\frac{\epsilon'}{C}$.

Comment: @JustinStevenson Makes sense, but there is a detail to be fixed. See my comment above.